# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^N \ln(n)- \int_{0}^N \ln x +o(1) \geq 0.5*\ln(N)$

Tags: integration, summation, logarithms, asymptotics

Question: Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^N \ln(n)- \int_{0}^N \ln x +o(1) \geq 0.5*\ln(N)$, where 0(1) is infinity small and N is the last number of sum. 
My thoughts: In the graphical representation of the difference of integral and sum there should be triangles, whose squares must be equal to this value.
Also there is no use of first element of the sum, because when n=0 -> lnn=0

Comment: It follows from Stirling's formula, but I presume that you don't want to use that.

Comment: @Lord , I dont know how to use it in this case. I know it is usually used to solve problems with factorial. Do you know how to solve it with Stirling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note:
I added an upper bound 
to go with the lower bound.

I also added a proof
that the series for
$\ln(1+x)$
is enveloping.

I will show
by elementary means that
$\frac12\ln(N)+\frac32
\gt \sum_{n=1}^N\ln(n)-\int_{0}^N \ln(x) dx
\gt \frac12\ln(N)+\frac13
$.

This shows that
$\ln(N!)
=N\ln(N)-N+\frac12\ln(N)
+c(N)
$
where
$\frac13
\lt c(N)
\lt \frac32
$.
This agrees with Stirling's
$\ln(\sqrt{2\pi})
\approx 0.9189$.

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(n)-\int_{n-1}^n \ln(x) dx
&=\ln(n)-(x\ln(x)-x)_{n-1}^n\\
&=\ln(n)-(n\ln(n)-n-((n-1)\ln(n-1)-(n-1)))\\
&=\ln(n)-(n\ln(n)-1-((n-1)\ln(n-1)))\\
&=1-((n-1)\ln(n)-((n-1)\ln(n-1)))\\
&=1-(n-1)(\ln(n)-\ln(n-1))\\
&=1-(n-1)\ln(\frac{n}{n-1})\\
&=1-(n-1)\ln(1+\frac{1}{n-1})\\
\end{array}
$

$\frac1{x}\ln(1+x)
=\frac1{x}(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-...)
=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}-...
$.

Since this series is enveloping
(see the discussion at the bottom),
$1-\frac{x}{2}
\lt \frac1{x}\ln(1+x)
\lt 1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}
$
or
$\frac{x}{2}
\gt 1-\frac1{x}\ln(1+x)
\gt \frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{3}
$.

Putting $x = \frac1{n-1}$,
$\frac{1}{2(n-1)}
\gt 1-(n-1)\ln(1+\frac1{n-1})
\gt \frac{1}{2(n-1)}-\frac{1}{3(n-1)^2}
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=2}^N\ln(n)-\int_{1}^N \ln(x) dx
&=\sum_{n=2}^N(\ln(n)-\int_{n-1}^n \ln(x) dx)\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^N(1-(n-1)\ln(1+\frac{1}{n-1}))\\
&>\sum_{n=2}^N(\frac{1}{2(n-1)}-\frac{1}{3(n-1)^2})\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{1}{2(n-1)}-\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{1}{3(n-1)^2}\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{n}-\frac13\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{n^2}\\
\text{and}\\
\sum_{n=2}^N\ln(n)-\int_{1}^N \ln(x) dx
&=\sum_{n=2}^N(1-(n-1)\ln(1+\frac{1}{n-1}))\\
&<\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{1}{2(n-1)}\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{n}\\
\end{array}
$

Since $\frac1{x}$
is decreasing for $x > 0$,
$\frac1{n}
\gt \int_n^{n+1} \frac{dx}{x}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{n}
&\gt \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \int_n^{n+1} \frac{dx}{x}\\
&=\int_1^N \frac{dx}{x}\\
&=\ln(N)\\
\end{array}
$

Similarly,
$\frac1{n}
\lt \int_{n-1}^{n} \frac{dx}{x}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{n}
&=1+\sum_{n=2}^{N-1}\frac{1}{n}\\
&\lt 1+\sum_{n=2}^{N-1} \int_{n-1}^{n} \frac{dx}{x}\\
&=1+\int_1^{N-1} \frac{dx}{x}\\
&=1+\ln(N-1)\\
&<1+\ln(N)\\
\end{array}
$

Also

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{n^2}
&=1+\sum_{n=2}^{N-1}\frac{1}{n^2}\\
&=1+\sum_{n=2}^{N-1}\frac{1}{n^2}\\
&<1+\sum_{n=2}^{N-1}\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\\
&=1+\sum_{n=2}^{N-1}(\frac1{n-1}-\frac1{n})\\
&=1+1-\frac1{N-1}\\
&< 2\\
\end{array}
$

so that
$\sum_{n=2}^N\ln(n)-\int_{1}^N \ln(x) dx
\gt \frac12\ln(N)-\frac23
$.

Since $\ln(1) = 0$
and
$\int_0^1 \ln(x) dx
=(x\ln(x)-x)_0^1
=-1
$,
$\sum_{n=1}^N\ln(n)-\int_{0}^N \ln(x) dx
\gt \frac12\ln(N)+\frac13
$.

Similarly,
$\sum_{n=2}^N\ln(n)-\int_{1}^N \ln(x) dx
\lt \frac12(1+\ln(N))
=\frac12+\frac12\ln(N) 
$
so that
$\sum_{n=1}^N\ln(n)-\int_{0}^N \ln(x) dx
\lt \frac12\ln(N)+\frac32
$.

On $\ln(1+x)$.

If $0 < x < 1$
and $m \in \mathbb{N}$,

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac1{1+x}
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} (-1)^n x^n+\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} (-1)^n x^n+(-1)^mx^m\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-m} x^{n-m}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} (-1)^n x^n+(-1)^mx^m\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} x^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} (-1)^n x^n+(-1)^mx^m\dfrac1{1+x}\\
\int_0^t \dfrac{dx}{1+x}
&=\int_0^t\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} (-1)^n x^n+\int_0^t(-1)^mx^m\dfrac1{1+x}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} (-1)^n \int_0^t x^ndx+(-1)^m\int_0^t\dfrac{x^mdx}{1+x}\\
\ln(1+t)
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} \dfrac{(-1)^nt^{n+1}}{n+1}+(-1)^m\int_0^t\dfrac{x^mdx}{1+x}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} \dfrac{(-1)^nt^{n+1}}{n+1}+(-1)^mE_m(t)\\
\end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
E_m(t)
&=\int_0^t\dfrac{x^mdx}{1+x}\\
&\lt\int_0^tx^mdx\\
&=\dfrac{t^{m+1}}{m+1}\\
\text{and}\\
E_m(t)
&=\int_0^t\dfrac{x^mdx}{1+x}\\
&\gt\int_0^t\dfrac{x^mdx}{1+t}\\
&=\dfrac{t^{m+1}}{(1+t)(m+1)}\\
\text{so}\\
0
&\lt \dfrac{t^{m+1}}{m+1}-E_m(t)\\
&\lt \dfrac{t^{m+1}}{m+1}-\dfrac{t^{m+1}}{(1+t)(m+1)}\\
&= \dfrac{t^{m+1}}{m+1}(1-\dfrac{1}{1+t})\\
&= \dfrac{t^{m+1}}{m+1}(\dfrac{t}{1+t})\\
&= \dfrac{t^{m+2}}{(m+1)(1+t)}\\
&< \dfrac{t^{m+2}}{m+1}\\
\end{array}
$